# How to set a checkbox handler that uses "this" parameter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, checkbox, onchange

In HTML I can write:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="MyBox" onchange="MyHandler(this.checked)">
```

Instead of specifying the handler in HTML, I want to set it TypeScript.  I tried:

```
document.getElementById('MyBox').onchange = function(){MyHandler(this.checked); };
```

but get the error "Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'".  How do you then access the attributes of "this"?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: type assertion

```ts
document.getElementById('MyBox')!.onchange = 
    function(){MyHandler((this as HTMLInputElement).checked); };
```

Here I've ommited checking the result of `getElementById`. Suppresing error with [non-null assert operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) `!`.

More or less type safe way:

```ts
(document.getElementById('MyBox') as HTMLInputElement)
    .addEventListener('change', function() { MyHandler(this.checked); })
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W44BKW)

You'll still have to type assert the result of `getElementById` since typescript cannot guess the result of runtime operation.

Production ready way:

```ts
function assertInput(element: HTMLElement | null): asserts element is HTMLInputElement {
    if (!element) throw new Error('Element not found on the page');
    if (element.tagName !== 'INPUT') throw new Error(`Element is not an input`)
}

const input = document.getElementById('MyBox')

assertInput(input)
input.addEventListener('change', function () { MyHandler(this.checked) })
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzyZ4m)